# Adding UISegmentedControl to UINavigationController's Toolbar with Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to add a UISegmentedControl to a UIToolbar using IB within xCode.

Whilst this is easy using a xib file, (create a view, add a toolbar to the bottom of the screen and drag on a UISegmentedControl onto the toolbar), it seems 'impossible' using storyboards.

I have a UIViewController scene embedded in a UINavigationController...

[image]

I have the following settings on the NavigationController...

[image]

I seem to be able to add UIBarButtonItems to the toolbar in the ViewController, not a UISegmentedControl as I can with xibs.

[image]

It even seems impossible to do via code...

```
let segmentControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["One","Two"]);
let segmentedControlButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: segmentControl);
let barArray = [segmentedControlButtonItem];
self.navigationController?.setToolbarItems(barArray, animated: false);
```

Surely this is doable via storyboards? I can add UISegmentControls to the top bar in the Navigation Controller, (via a UIView) but not to the bottom toolbar.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the toolbarItems of your own ViewController, this will propagate to the NavigationController:

```
self.toolbarItems = barArray
```

I haven't found a way of adding a SegmentedControl via Storyboards, which I would prefer as well.